# setAttribute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

```
var addColor = [
            {
                "option": "opt1",
                "value": "empty",
                "id": "white",
                "name": "Color"
            },
            {
                "option": "opt2",
                "value": "#60afdc",
                "id": "blue",
                "name": "Blue #60afdc"
            },
            {
                "option": "opt3",
                "value": "#f4a700",
                "id": "yellow",
                "name": "Yellow #f4a700"
            },
            {
                "option": "opt4",
                "value": "#c70049",
                "id": "ruby",
                "name": "Ruby-red #c70049"
            },
            {
                "option": "opt5",
                "value": "#000",
                "id": "black",
                "name": "Black #000"
            },
        ]

        function addCol() {
            console.log(addColor);
            addColor.forEach((opt, i) => {
                **opt1**.setAttribute('value', `${opt.value}`);
                **opt1**.setAttribute('id', `${opt.id}`);
                **opt1**.innerHTML = `${opt.name}`;
                select.appendChild(**opt1**);
            });
        }
        addCol();
```

How do I get the opt1 to add up? I have tried to add, `${opt.option}` there but that dosent work.

Is there any nicer way to do this? I want to be able to add value, id and name, easily if I came up with a new color in my dropdown.

Comment: What is your requirement?? What you need to do actually with the array provided??

Comment: The array is there for me to easily add a new color in my dropdown, if I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const select = document.getElementById('select');
        function addCol() {
            addColor.forEach((opt, i) => {
             let op = document.createElement('option');
            op.value = opt.value;
            op.innerHTML = opt.name;
            op.id=opt.id;
            select.appendChild(op);
            });
        }
        addCol();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your requirement is to create some option tags and append to select -

Do this in your foreach loop-

```
addColor.forEach((opt) => {
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.setAttribute('value', opt.value);
    option.setAttribute('id', opt.id);
    option.innerHTML = opt.name;
    select.appendChild(option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `option` using `document.createElement` and add necessary attributes

```js
var addColor = [{
    "option": "opt1",
    "value": "empty",
    "id": "white",
    "name": "Color"
  },
  {
    "option": "opt2",
    "value": "#60afdc",
    "id": "blue",
    "name": "Blue #60afdc"
  },
  {
    "option": "opt3",
    "value": "#f4a700",
    "id": "yellow",
    "name": "Yellow #f4a700"
  },
  {
    "option": "opt4",
    "value": "#c70049",
    "id": "ruby",
    "name": "Ruby-red #c70049"
  },
  {
    "option": "opt5",
    "value": "#000",
    "id": "black",
    "name": "Black #000"
  },
]
const select = document.getElementById('select');

function addCol() {
  addColor.forEach((opt, i) => {
    const currElem = document.createElement('option');
    currElem.setAttribute('value', `${opt.value}`);
    currElem.setAttribute('id', `${opt.id}`);
    currElem.innerHTML = `${opt.name}`;
    select.appendChild(currElem);
  });
}
addCol();
```

```html
<select id='select'></select>
```

Comment: What is `opts + (i+1)`, isn't it just a string ?, how can you do setAttribute on it ?

Comment: I keep ending up with TypeError: xxx.setAttribute is not a function when I tries to change the number, someway.